# Issue with EntityPlayer.posX "flickering" between values

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So basically I'm trying to create a coords display mod. When accessing the player's position with posX/Y/Z (this example uses X) there is a weird "flickering" with the displayed coordinate. You can see it in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BJlhxfUfac) video.

```
@SubscribeEvent
public void playerTick(PlayerTickEvent event) {
    EntityPlayer player = event.player;
    
    posX = player.posX;
    System.out.println(posX); // Used to debug, also had the issue, meaning it isn't an issue with round()
}

@SubscribeEvent
public void renderOverlay(RenderGameOverlayEvent event) {
    if (event.type == RenderGameOverlayEvent.ElementType.TEXT) {
        drawString(renderer, String.valueOf(round(posX, 8)), 0, 0, -1);
    }
}
```

I think this might have something to do with me using playerTick or something, but I'm new to forge and Java and don't know what I might use instead (assuming that is the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with me using PlayerTickEvent instead of ClientTickEvent.

```
public void clientTick(ClientTickEvent event) {
    
    EntityPlayerSP player = mc.thePlayer;
    if (player == null) return;
    
    posX = player.posX
}
```

`if (player == null) return;` is required because when not in game, `mc.thePlayer` returns `null` so `.posX` causes a crash.